# UIBezierPath in CALayer with wrong color

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a UIBezierPath in my CALayer. I add but it is a black rectangle and I've tried to draw a clearColor rectangle with red border.

There's my code:

```
    let rectangle: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/2 - 30, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 60))
    UIColor.clearColor().setFill()
    rectangle.fill()
    UIColor.redColor().setStroke()
    rectangle.lineWidth = 1
    rectangle.stroke()

    let boundingLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
    boundingLayer.path = rectangle.CGPath
    capturePreviewLayer.addSublayer(boundingLayer)
```

Comment: You should apply fill color and stroke color to `boundingLayer`

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. Answer it and I mark as resolved